# Unpack multiple values and store into database is failing

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I have a function that I'm `calling insert_into_db_tmp()` . But, when I go to execute it, its using the full representation, instead of the value of `test.com/test2` and `path`.

`calling insert_into_db_tmp()` declaration looks like:

```
def insert_into_db_tmp(dbcursor, table, col, val):
    try:
        query = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)",(table, ",".join(col), ",".join(val))
        print(query)
        dbcursor.execute(query)
        print("inserted!")
    except pymysql.Error as exc:
        print("error inserting...\n {}".format(exc))
```

I'm calling this like:

```
connection=conn_db()
table = ['test']
col = ['path',]
val = ['test.com/test2',]
insert_into_db_tmp(connection, settings.dni+table,str(col),str(val))
```

When I execute this, I get this:

```
INSERT INTO test () VALUES ('{'vals': ['test.com/test2'], 'cols': ['path']}')
error inserting...
 (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'vals': ['test.com/test2'], 'cols': ['path']}')' at line 1")
```

Note: the goal of `insert_into_db_tmp()` is to allow multiple `col` to be entered, and multiple `val`. So they're representation might look like in the future:

```
cols=['path','address']
vals=['somesite.com/id=6', '123 Hector Lane']
```

Can someone please help me resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Use proper parameter substitution for your values, not `format`.

Comment: @AlexHall - can you create an answer please.

Comment: No, google "python mysql parameter substitution" and make an attempt.

Comment: @Alex - its actually not as simple as the SELECT examples found.

Comment: Also, I updated my `query` with the "proper parameterization...and still get the same error, so while I might have made the code look a little better the root problem isnt fixed.

Comment: It's not about making the code a little better, it's steps towards fixing the problem. You *should* use `format` for the table and column names, as those cannot be substituted. You should be passing two arguments to execute, not a pair with two values. You actually need to use executemany. And there needs to be a `%s` placeholder for each column in the VALUES section at the end.

Comment: @AlexHall - please provide this response with example code, I'm not following.

Comment: Also, I'm only passing `1` value to VALUES, since im only operating on `1` column, but still getting the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170430/discussion-between-alex-hall-and-john).